# Helper class for MVC ASP website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have severals classes with CRUD operations, when there is a action, I create a sort of activity feed. For now, this is the code I use in a method.

```
            var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
            var claims = identity.Claims;
            var username = claims.First(k => k.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
            var user = _db.Users.First(k => k.Username == username);

            _db.ActivityFlows.Add(new ActivityFlow()
            {
                FolderID = folder.FolderID,
                UserID = user.UserID, 
                Description = user.FullName + " as created the part",
                CreationDate = DateTime.Now
            });
            _db.SaveChanges();
```

I tried to put it in a helper class, but the `User.Identity` is null. I tried to put it in the model on creation of an class, same problem.

What is the cleanest way to do it?

I'm using MVC 5 asp.net with Entity Framework code first.

Comment: You could do this in an `ActionFilter`(More information about action filters: http://blog.falafel.com/custom-filter-asp-net-mvc-5/, https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs)

Comment: You could create a baseController class that can be inherited by your controller class. In the baseController class add the helper. You are probably getting null from your helper because the helper does not know anything about the httpcontext, but the controller does. Still if you want to use your helper just pass the httpcontext.